# Displays all data on the same user_id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show all posts by one of my site visitors who have logged in and written an article.

**Table**

```
---------------------------------------------
user_id     |   title       |   content
---------------------------------------------
1           |   title one   |   content one
1           |   title two   |   content two
1           |   title three |   content three
---------------------------------------------
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$postRow=$query->fetch_array();

$conn->close();

echo "<li>". $postRow['title'] ."</li>";

?>
```

**RESULT:**

- title one

**How to display:**

- title one
- title two
- title three

I really appreciate any input. thanks.

Comment: A: you need a loop and this has been asked many times. Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php --- Edit: and the duplicates.

Comment: Use while($row = $result->fetch_array())